# Verificación en dos pasos con php sonata-Project/google-authenticator no funciona

Tags: php, autenticación

Estoy tratando de añadir esta verificación de dos pasos con Google Authenticator y aunque la imagen QR se genera correctamente con los datos correctos (correo del usuario y nombre del sitio) al generar los códigos estos siempre son erroneos.

Ampliando un poco: al mostrase el código QR en pantalla, lo escaneo con las Apps tanto de Google como de Microsoft, en teoría se puede usar cualquier app de autenticación; después de escanear, el sitio se registra correctamente en las Apps y comienzan a generar códigos, los pruebo usando la forma y al enviarlos siempre son erróneos - Incorrect or expired code -

No sé si tengo algo mal en mi código, al parecer no, pero no encuentro la falla.

Gracias!

```
<?php 

include_once 'vendor/sonata-project/google-authenticator/src/FixedBitNotation.php';
include_once 'vendor/sonata-Project/google-authenticator/src/GoogleAuthenticatorInterface.php';
include_once 'vendor/sonata-project/google-authenticator/src/GoogleAuthenticator.php';
include_once 'vendor/sonata-project/google-authenticator/src/GoogleQrUrl.php';

$g = new \Google\Authenticator\GoogleAuthenticator();
$secret = 'JHGDJ67HYTR398TR';
//$secret = $g->generateSecret();

$mail = "test@whatever.com";

$qrAUT =  \Sonata\GoogleAuthenticator\GoogleQrUrl::generate($mail, $secret, 'TEST SITE'); 
 echo '<img src="'.$qrAUT.'" /><br><br>';
?>

<form action="">
  <label for="fname">Code:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="code" name="code" value=""><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<?
$code = $_GET['code'];

if($g->checkCode($secret, $code)){
    echo $code . ' Authorized!';
}
else{
    echo $code . ' Incorrect or expired code!';
}
?>
```